# 401 Unauthorized access for Github API (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, access-token, http-status-code-401, github-api

I have generated the access_token by using the [URL](http://develop.github.com/p/oauth.html) provided by GitHub. I am able to do all the GET operations on the api with the [URL](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/). What i really wish to do is the POST operation. I wish to create an issue from my Rails app.

Every time i try to do that, i get a 401 unauthorized access by GitHub despite the fact that i am sending the `access_token` in params on this [URL](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue).

I have also tried it with these gems :: [Github V3 API](https://github.com/jwilger/github-v3-api) and [Octopi](https://github.com/fcoury/octopi)

There are other questions similar to this, but the solution has not been found it seems.

**EDIT** :: I wish to add `title` to create an issue

Comment: What's the code you're using to POST, and is the repo private, by chance (and being POST'ed to by a user that doesn't have access)?

Comment: none of them is the case. The repo is not private. I wish to post `title` which is the only require string when it comes to creating an issue. http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue

Comment: I have also created an issue on github-v3-api gem. https://github.com/jwilger/github-v3-api/issues/8